# set block to appear after page view

Tags: views, blocks

This is probably a simple question, but how do you ensure a page view sites above a block on a page? Currently I have a page view which displays some content and then have a block view which holds some other content.This block view was added to the page view via the blocks page. Problem is the block appears before the page view content, any ideas on how to reorder this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, the answer should be as simple as changing the block region :
go to:
https://www.example.com/admin/structure/block

and change the specified block region to footer or a region below "main content region".

You may check regions positioning by clicking on "Demonstrate block regions (Your-Theme-name)"

Comment: The issue is that some of the content is produced as part of a page view and not as a block. The block content however seems to displace it and push it down. What I want to happen is for the page content to stay above the block.